# Index of NowPlayingItem is wronging when Shuffle Mode is on in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, shuffle, mpmediaitem

I'm now playing song from iPod Library that loaded into myArray with `iPodMusicPlayer`.

We can use `indexOfNowPlayingItem` to get index from NowPlaying music.

But when i `Shuffle Mode` is `on`, that `indexOfNowPlayingItem` Property's return index is completely wrong.

before `ShuffleMode` is off,`indexOfNowPlayingItem` can be used and correct.

However when `ShuffleMode` is on, indexOfNowPlayingItem count is only increase 1 (++).

like that

```
indexOfNowPlayingItem++;
```

Not a correct for `ShuffleMode` on.

So how can i get correct index when ShuffleMode on?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Same here.... Did you manage to solve this? Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: no bro. i can't find any solution about that. :(

Answer (score 2):

My solution was when you set your playlist, set also a NSMutableDictionary with (index, MPMediaEntityPropertyPersistentID) of playlist.

When you need the song index, just get with the song persistent id.

```
- (void) setPlaylistIndexDictionary:(MPMediaItemCollection *)playlistItems
{
    playlistIndexDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSNumber *count = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:0];
    for (MPMediaItem *item in [playlistItems items]) {
        [playlistIndexDict setObject:count forKey:[item valueForProperty:MPMediaEntityPropertyPersistentID]];
        count = [NSNumber numberWithInt:count.intValue + 1];
    }
}


- (NSString *) getCurrentSongId
{
    NSString* songId = [[musicPlayer nowPlayingItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaEntityPropertyPersistentID];

    return songId;
}
```

Using:

```
NSString *songId = [musicController getCurrentSongId];
int songIndex = [[[musicController playlistIndexDict] objectForKey:songId] intValue];
```